# Select descendants from has_many association in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, select, count

So I have a list of `sources` and have `entries`. Entries have a field `source_id` to reference the `Source`. Now I need to get the count of `entries` for a number of `sources`, via the `user_id` field which is a field in `sources`.

So basically I need to select all `source` IDs from a certain `user_id` and then through those IDs, get a number of `entries`. I tried the following:

```
entries_count = Source.where('user_id = ?', user_id).entries.count
```

But this obviously didn't work.

What would be the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`entries_count = Sources.where('user_id = ?', user_id)` will return a collection, not an object. So you have to get each collection element's entries first, and count after:

```
entries_count = Sources.where('user_id = ?', user_id).map(&:entries).flatten.count
```

Unrelated thing: is you model really called `Sources` or it is a typo and it's `Source` in fact?

Comment: No, it's `Source`, just a typo :). Thanks I'll try this now!

Answer (score 0):

I would go from entries to sources using

```
Entry.joins(:source).where(sources: {user_id: user_id}).count
```